# Sorting large numbers

Tags: python, sorting, largenumber

If one has a list of very very large numbers in Python, so much so that the compiler cannot get the value of them as numbers. Is there a function to sort this list (while keeping the numbers as integers) in a more efficient way such as comparing number to number? (But without converting to string)

Comment: Python handles large numbers without problems. Try `1 << 1000`.

Comment: How large are your numbers? The sys.maxsize + 1 should be promoted to long, and the amount of available address space is a limit for your numbers.

Comment: What compiler? Python can handle arbitrarily large integers. Your limit is memory and CPU time...

Comment: Do you have any examples of these numbers you can including in your question? Please include them as part of solid: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a solution that works for other languages. You could have a list of list of integers. So basically, given a number like 123456789, you could represent it as

```
bigNum = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comparing big numbers could be done by the following:

- Compare the number of digits
- If the number of digits are equal, compare the numbers starting from the largest digit.

Answer (score 7):

Both Python 2 and Python 3 handle arbitrarily large integers:

```
>>> [2**34, 2**38, 2**99, 2**122, 2]
[17179869184, 274877906944, 633825300114114700748351602688L, 5316911983139663491615228241121378304L, 2]
```

And sort them as expected:

```
>>> sorted(_)
[2, 17179869184, 274877906944, 633825300114114700748351602688L, 5316911983139663491615228241121378304L]
```

(Python 2 will show a `L` for integers larger than sys.maxint as in the example here while Python 3 shows the integer values the same for smaller or larger integers)